# Анимация jQuery не работает на 1.9.0

Tags: jquery

Есть скрипт, который выводит анимацию. Он работает на jQuery 1.5.1, а на 1.9.0 - нет.
Какие есть альтернативы записи анимации?

```
$('#send').click(function() {
    var obj = $.browser.webkit ? $('body') : $('html');
    obj.animate({ scrollTop: $('#jform').offset().top }, 750, function() {
        jVal.errors = false;
        jVal.fullName();
        jVal.birthDate();
        jVal.gender();
        jVal.vehicle();
        jVal.email();
        jVal.about();
        jVal.sendIt();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Удалили `$.browser` в версии 1.9.

Comment: И, собственно, [документация по этому поводу](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/).

Comment: спасибо, убрал $.browser и заработало

Comment: @LLIAKAJI кстати, а вас не беспокоила ошибка `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'webkit' of undefined` в консоли? Она недвусмысленно намекает на то в чем проблема.

Comment: Regent, открывал firebug и смотрел в консоль, там ничего не выводило

Comment: @LLIAKAJI необходимо добавлять `@` перед ником, чтобы человеку приходило оповещение о вашем ответе. По поводу ошибок: в [этом fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amagx4nd/) у вас тоже ошибки в консоли нет?